# How to disable tab symbols from Visual Studio editor

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2013 Express. While editor was running some keys where pressed which activated tab symbols. Now each tab stop i can see a symbol(->).

Where can i find the option to disable symbols.

*I have looked in Tools->Text Editor->C/C++->Tabs*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle this setting via menu *Edit* -> *Advanced* -> *View White Space*

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following control keys to toggle between displaying the whitespaces

```
Ctrl+r, Ctrl+w
```

or edit the option under the Edit Menu:

```
Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space
```

[image: whitespace]

You can refer to the [keyboard shortcuts](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/)